# AttributeError inserting into lxml Tree in Python

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to inject a small structure of xml into a specific location in an already existing xml file:

```
<not>
  <elt>
    <isVal>Y</isVal>
  </elt>
</not>
```

My code looks like this:

```
import lxml.etree as ElementTree;

tree = ElementTree.ElementTree()
tree.parse(file_path)

root = tree.getroot();
ruleElement = tree.find('.//rule');

for child_n in ruleElement:
    if (child_n.tag == 'and'):
        print "Found rule - and"
        ruleElement.insert(0, tree.XML("<not><elt><isVal>Y</isVal></elt></not>"))
```

I get the following error:
**AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'XML'**

I have also tried:

```
for child_n in ruleElement:
    if (child_n.tag == 'and'):
        print "Found rule - and"
        child_n.Element(child_n, 'test_insert').text = 'test'
        child_n.insert(1, item[0])
```

This gives:
**AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._ElementTree' object has no attribute 'Element'**

Tried it as SubElement, got the same error message:
**AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'SubElement'**

I got the ideas on how to do it from other similar questions but it just doesn't seem to want to accept Element, SubElement or XML as acceptable attributes.  What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Python 2.6, upgrading isn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create 'elements' using `lxml.etree.SubElement`:

```
import lxml.etree

xml = lxml.etree.parse('xyz.xml')
root = xml.getroot()

nt = lxml.etree.SubElement(root, 'not')  # add to the XML root!
elt = lxml.etree.SubElement(nt, 'elt')
isVal = lxml.etree.SubElement(elt, 'isVal')
isVal.text = 'Y'

with open("xyz2.xml", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(lxml.etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8"))

print(open("xyz2.xml", 'r').read())
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<note>
  <to>abc</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Party</body>
<not><elt><isVal>Y</isVal></elt></not></note>
```